# Type mismatch error in Scala

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I am blocked since yesterday about a type mismatch error and I don't see how to correct it. Maybe you can help me with it.

```
def combine( head : (Char,Int), xs : Occurrences) : List[Occurrences] =
 xs.map { case (x,i) => for ( occu <- 1 to head._2 ) yield List((x,i), (head._1, occu)) }
```

Here is the error that I get :

```
type mismatch; 
found :   List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[(Char, Int)]]]   
required: List[forcomp.Anagrams.Occurrences]
```

The type `Occurrences` is defined as  `type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve your problem by using flatMap which will concatenate (flatten) the Lists for you.

```
def combine( head : (Char,Int), xs : Occurrences) : List[Occurrences] =
  xs.flatMap { case (x,i) => (1 to head._2).map(occu =>List((x,i), (head._1, occu))) }
```

Now for each occurance it'll produce a list that has the `(x,i)` tuple and the `(head._1, occu)` tuple and all of the lists will essentially be `++`'d together by the flatMap.

Note that I'm blindly converting your code since I know this is homework so I won't attempt to analyze if the algorithm is correct.

Comment: Don't worry, based on your answer, I finally find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for each member of `Occurrences` you yield a List – so you get something like a `List[List[Occurrences]]`. I guess you might use `flatMap` instead of `map` which will flatten the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot flatMap !!